# how to stop socket keeps writing data in loop java

Tags: java, file, sockets

I have made server client application where server will send a file to client and client will receive it and save it in C:/ on any place.
I first send a string "File" in order to tell client to receive file and than server send file name and size to client and then start sending it.
Problem is that client doesnt receive file although it read in loop and get all bytes but doesnt write to required file object. Please have a look on client code I HAVE SHOWN WHERE IT STUCKS

Following is server code :

```
public void run(){
    try{
        System.out.println("Starting writing file");
        objOut.writeObject("File");
        objOut.flush();

        File f= new File(filePath);
        String name= f.getName();
        int length =(int) f.length();
        objOut.writeObject(name);
        objOut.flush();

        objOut.writeObject(length);
        objOut.flush();

        byte[] filebytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
        FileInputStream fin= new FileInputStream(f);
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);

        bin.read(filebytes, 0, filebytes.length);
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(objOut);
        bout = new BufferedOutputStream(objOut);
        bout.write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.length);
        bout.flush();      
        System.out.println("File completelty sent");

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("error on writing file : "+ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Following is client code :

```
 while(true){
            fobjIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileSock.getInputStream());
            String str = (String) fobjIn.readObject();
            if(str.equals("File"))
            {
                System.out.println("Starting receiving file");
                ReceiveFile();
            }
            System.out.println(str);
        }

 public void ReceiveFile() throws Exception{

     String name =(String)fobjIn.readObject();
   File f = new File("C:/Temp/" +name);
   f.createNewFile();
   int length = (int) fobjIn.readObject();
   FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
   BufferedOutputStream buffout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
   byte[] filebyte = new byte[length];
   int bytesRead=0,current=0;
   bytesRead = fobjIn.read(filebyte, 0, filebyte.length);
    do {
        bytesRead = fobjIn.read(filebyte, current, (filebyte.length-current));
        if(bytesRead > 0) {
            current += bytesRead;
            System.out.println("writting" + bytesRead);
        }
        else break;
     } while(bytesRead > -1);
```

^^^^^^^**IT DOESNT COMEOUT FROM LOOP while begugging**^^^^^^^^

```
    buffout.write(filebyte, 0 , current);
    buffout.flush();
    System.out.println("written");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably close your stream on the server side when you are done sending, so that the client can be notified that the server is done sending. Or else it'll just sit there waiting for more data.

Comment: and please have a look on code , is it fine ? loops and other things ? reading

Comment: also when it server want to send another file than how it will send , if streams are closed. ?

Comment: If you want your server to send multiple files, then it needs to send a code when the file is done being sent instead of closing the stream. The client has to be looking for that code (a pre-defined multi-bytes sequence probably).

Comment: thank you , file received when i closed the port , also can you please explain me how i can set client to read that string while its in loop to discontinue and write to file ?

Comment: actually, since you're also sending the file size at the beginning, you just have to read it within you `do {} while` loop instead of before it. Then it should just work right away.